manipulate php config file
What's the correct way to automate manipulation of a php config file of this format?
sample.php:

<?php
return [
    'someobject' => [
        'somefield' => 'somevalue'
    ]
];

I was thinking of converting it to JSON (json_encode), manipulate the JSON and writing it back afterwards (json_decode). But the last step gives me a different data format.
# !/bin/bash

# load data to json
JSON=$(php -r "echo json_encode(include 'sample.php');")
# manipulate json with jq
NEW_JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq -cr '.someobject.somefield = "othervalue"')
# write back
php -r "var_dump(json_decode('$NEW_JSON', true));" > sample2.php

The content I'm getting from json_decode is:
array(1) {
  ["someobject"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["somefield"]=>
    string(10) "othervalue"
  }
}

# or without true in json_decode

object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["someobject"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["somefield"]=>
    string(10) "othervalue"
  }
}

What's the correct way of manipulating this type of config files?

a php config file...that isn't a config file, or anything special, it's just executable code. It happens to contain a hard-coded array of data, but that's all. It's not truly parseable in the way you're hoping for - or not without a lot of unnecessary difficulty (just look at your messy bash script!). If you want to store config data, store it in an actual data format, such as JSON or XML. Then you can update it using standard tools.

P.S. the last step gives me a different data format...only because that's the format var_dump uses (as per its documentation and examples). If you want something which looks like PHP code and is parseable as such, use var_export instead. But this is still a daft, overcomplicated way to store and manipulate such config data in the first place.

Why export to another format, to then import it again, instead of manipulating the data directly in PHP? You already invoke the php CLI from the shell. Stay there, alter the parts you want to change, and then try replicating your original return code by exporting the value to valid PHP code.
php -r '
  $in = include $argv[1]; $in["someobject"]["somefield"] = "othervalue";
  $out = var_export($in,true); echo "<?php\nreturn {$out};";
' sample.php > sample2.php

Some notes:

For safety reasons, you might want to also perform some sanity checks before the export, e.g. employing functions like is_resource, etc.
For aesthetical reasons, you could replace var_export with a use of the var_representation extension to make the result look even more like your original
For interoperability reasons, you should consider storing your data as data (there are standard data processors for every data format), not as code

